# Binding Data to a Label in DetailView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, detailsview

I have two tables in a database.

```
Tables:
       email
            -typeId     **Foreign Key**
            -mxRecord
            -clientId
       emailType
            -typeId     **Primary Key**
            -typeName
```

What I'm trying to do, is in a Detailview that displays the table 'email' is instead of it showing a number for 'typeId', I would like it to show the value 'typeName'.

```
The contents of the tables:

email
        typeId      mxRecord     clientId
           1          NULL           1
           3          NULL           2
           2          NULL           3

emailType
        typeId      typeName
           1        Exchange
           2          POP3
           3         Hosted
```

I added a dropdownlist to select the appropriate client. (@i1 is the dropdown reference)

```
SQL:
     SELECT emailType.*, email.* FROM email 
     INNER JOIN emailType ON email.typeId = emailType.typeId 
     WHERE email.clientId = @i1
```

The detailsview for looks like this:

```
type       1
mxRecord   NULL
clientId   1
```

and I want it to look like this..

```
type       Exchange
mxRecord   NULL
clientId   1
```

Comment: Now that we know what's in the tables, can you show us what you have tried in your page?

Comment: All there is on my page is a detailsview, and a datasource pointing to the email table.  Not to much to show you other than what I have in my tables and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: In that case, can you show us the SQL you are using?

Comment: I added some more detail to help you see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Then I would suggest you modify the query to select only those specific fields, and in order, that you want.

Comment: Wow, I think I was just thinking to hard. Thank you Dean and Slider. Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a SqlDataSource with the query included above, this is just a matter of creating a boundfield entry inside your DetailsView for the typeName column.

Switch to your Source view and you should easily be able to make this look as so:

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="typeId, clientId" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="typeName" HeaderText="type" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="typeName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="mxRecord" HeaderText="mxRecord" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="mxRecord" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="clientId" HeaderText="clientId" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="clientId" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```